# jquery/ajax, check username avaibility

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm newbie of jquery and ajax, for my training, I create a form that check the username (and others) availability.

**form code:**

```
<h3 align="center">Daftar</h3>
<form action="do_regis.php" name="daftar" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_daftar()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username :</label>
        <input type="text" style="max-width:90%;" class="form-control" name="id_daftar" id="id_daftar" placeholder="Masukkan Username Anda" maxlength="16" autocomplete="off"/>
        <div class="error" id="idErr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" style="max-width:90%;" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Masukkan Password Anda" maxlength="16" value="" />
        <input type="checkbox" onclick=password()> Tampil Password
        <div class="error" id="passErr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nama">Nama :</label>
        <input type="text" style="max-width:90%" class="form-control" name="nama" id="nama" maxlength="50" placeholder="Masukkan Nama Sesuai KTP"  value="" />
        <div class="error" id="namaErr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="email" style="max-width:90%;" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Masukkan Email Anda" value="" />
        <div class="error" id="emailErr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nomorhp">Nomor HP:</label>
        <input type="number" style="max-width:90%;" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukkan Nomor HP Anda" name="nohp" id="nohp" maxlength="16" value="" />
        <div class="error" id="nohpErr"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="daftar" value="daftar" class="btn btn-info">Daftar</button>
</form>
```

**jquery code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_daftar').keyup(function(){
        var id_daftar = $('#id_daftar').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "regis_username.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "id_daftar="+id_daftar,
            success: function(data)
            {       
                if(data == 1)
                {
                    $("#idErr").html("username tersedia");
                    $("#idErr").css("outline-color", "green");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#idErr").html("username tidak tersedia");
                    $("#idErr").css("outline-color", "red");
                    console.log(id_daftar);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
        });
    });

    $("#nama").keyup(function(){
        var nama = $('#nama').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "regis_nama.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "nama="+nama,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data == 0)
                {
                    $("#namaErr").html("name avaible");
                    $("#namaErr").css("color", "green");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#namaErr").html("name not avaible");
                    console.log(nama);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
        });  
    });

    $("#email").keyup(function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "regis_email.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "email="+email,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data==0)
                {
                    $("#emailErr").html("email avaible");
                    $("#emailErr").css("color", "green");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#emailErr").html("email not avaible!");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
        });  
    });

    $("#nohp").keyup(function(){
        var nohp = $("#nohp").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "regis_nohp.php",
            type: "post",
            data: "nohp="+nohp,
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data==0)
                {
                    $("#nohpErr").html("phone number avaible");
                    $("#nohpErr").css("color", "green");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#nohpErr").html("phone number not avaible!");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            },
        });  
    });

});
```

**Here are the searching code** (regis_username.php):

```
<?php
     include "koneksi.php";

     $username = $_POST['id_daftar'];

     $sql= "select * from login where username = '$username' ";
     $query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

     echo $count;
?>
```

after i test it, its not working (showing else statement even the value is 1) and the console.log(data) contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is wrong, but any help and explanation will be appreciated
thanks!

Comment: does your `regis_username.php` have html code as well ?

Comment: no, just php code

Comment: What does `koneksi.php` contain? The console data would indicate that something is trying to create output other than just the count.

Comment: its about connection to database


`<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hotel");
if (!$conn) {
 die ("Connection Failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>`